# How to Redirect Subdirectory to Parent Directory .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, litespeed, openlitespeed

For quite a while, I've been observing the 404 error log file, and I found that from nowhere, the visitors landed in subdirectories containing numbers that don't exist. And there are more than 50% humans. Although the parent directory does exist, instead of getting back to the parent directory, they are seeing another page that I've set for 404 errors (in simple words, they see a 404 error).

**For example:**

```
https://www.example.com/crush/1000
```

In the upper URL, I don't know who referred to this page with an ending of 1000, and it's not on my server. Now this page will redirect you to `https://www.example.com/list/` as I set it, instead of seeing the typical 404 error page.

***Now what I want to do is redirect any visitor who visits such pages to the parent directory using `.htaccess`, i.e.***

```
https://www.example.com/crush/
```

Remember, the value 1000 is not a fixed value; it could be any number, even including points (`.`) and slashes (`/`).

**A few examples are:**

- `https://www.example.com/bon-appetit/0.192840405`
- `https://www.example.com/new-kid-on-the-block//100000`
- `https://www.example.com/list/alphabetical/0.12417095834474612`
- `https://www.example.com/a-quick-buck/&ved=2aqfnoecc4qag&usg=aovvaw3ed5h`

NOTE: I'm using LiteSpeed not Apache.

Your help is highly appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK litespeed can process a `RewriteRule` in the apache style. So why can't you simply implement such a rule that matches any request that ends in such a numeric string? So something like `RewriteRule ^/?([^/]+)/[\d.]+$ /$1/`? (I ignored that last example you gave, it does not appear to fit into your description)

Comment: Actually, I am quite bad at .htaccess rules and conditions. Honestly, I won't ask if I can find a way. I will be grateful if you can explain it a bit more, please. Thanks

Comment: That last example looks like a malformed query string. Do the URL parameters `ved` and `usg` mean anything to your site?

Comment: @MrWhite Hi, actually, no. We don't use query strings much, and we don't recognize them.

Comment: "observing the 404 error log file" - 404 responses should be logged in the "access log". (Do you have a dedicated log file just for 404 responses?) "there are more than 50% humans" - This sounds unusually high, particularly when you don't know where these are coming from. How have you determined they are "human" requests? Have you checked the "HTTP Referer"?

Comment: @MrWhite

See Screenshot: https://ibb.co/0MgWNBM Actually, a Wordpress plugin called 301 Redirect Pro keeps a log of all those 404 redirects. Unfortunately, it doesn't have the option to match queries, so I have to manually add such a type of page, which is an endless process and can be fixed with a .htaccess code. Screenshot: https://ibb.co/0MgWNBM 

Currently showing 34% humans, I've deactivated it. It's a log of one day and can reach up to 75%.